# In the Biology SE I have posted a question on may 31,2019.After some days it got deleted by community◆mod(system).Please,can you undelete it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The question which I have posted got automatically deleted on June 21,2019 at 3am IST by community◆ moderator(system).Before that it got closed as too broad.I need to answer that question which was posted by me. I was unable to use internet when these things were going on.I'm sad with this deletion. Please undelete the question so that I can answer. Do I need to edit the question first?

Comment: as the [answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3978/16866) says below, you can simply repost the question (something like "Do all mammal species protect their offspring from predation?".). However, unless you were to make the post more specific and provide some explicit indication that you've researched the question on your own, the post would be closed like your now-deleted initial attempt. Please review the help pages in the [answer](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3978/16866) below for more info for writing good questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A *lot* of Qs are put on hold, closed and subsequently deleted. We can't possibly recover it for you after such a long time. I'm sorry to hear it makes you feel bad. You could simply ask the question again. Make sure to:

- add your **prior research**;
- make the question **specific**;
- include **references and sources**;
- ***not*** generate self-help posts.

See the [help center here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for information on asking good questions.

<sub>**Related**

**-** [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675)

**-** [How can a question deleted by community be undeleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/how-can-a-question-deleted-by-community-be-undeleted)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

First of all: This is not true, your question got automatically deleted by the system as "RemoveAbandonedClosed", 20 days after it was closed by community vote as too broad. This eventually happens to most closed/abandoned questions to avoid collecting a lot of these.

You could have edited and made the question better focussed in the almost three weeks between it has been closed and **before** it was deleted. You chose to not take this chance, so I see no reason to do it now.

And please: Stop posting "questions" on the main site to undelete this, as this will not happen. If you choose to ask the question again, make it more focussed to avoid another closure.

Comment: Initially i told that my question got automatically deleted by community◆ but it got edited.I didn't say it was deleted by a community moderator.I'm sorry as I was unable to take the chance

Comment: I'm sorry I was unable to take the chance in those days.please undelete it if you are able to do that.i don't want to post the question again.

Comment: I know you have lot of things to do in this site.I may be disturbing you when you are busy.I'm sorry for that.I don't know how to convince you.Please undelete the question.should I send you the link? I don't want to post the question newly.

Comment: @user Please read the answers from AliceD and Chris in their entirety and follow the links for more information. Asking a 8th, 9th, even 10th time will not change the result. If you aren't willing to put in the effort on your own question, why should you expect anyone to put the effort into an answer?